# How can I optimize a VBA code for a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a UserForm to enter data into columns of the same row. It's essentially a checklist that the user will select to better organize data on a long excel sheet. I have it somewhat working but the more I add the more complicated and the longer the code gets. I have a feeling I could somehow use a subroutine or ranges to have the same options for every cell in a range but can't get it to work. I am also very new to VBA.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Dim SAT
Dim keepvalue
Dim units
Dim complete
Dim commagent

Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
' Hides User Form - "Cancel" Button
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox14_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Writes the values of the combobox's into the respective cells
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox2.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox4.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox1.Value & units
    
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox3.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox4.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = ComboBox5.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = ComboBox6.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = ComboBox7.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = ComboBox8.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = ComboBox9.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = ComboBox10.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = ComboBox11.Value

    
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Application.UserName

    
    ' Gets current date and writes into respective cell
    Dim dtToday As Date
    dtToday = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Date
    


    
    ' If colorbox1 And colorbox2 = 1 Then
    ' ActiveCell.Offset.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    ' End If

    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
Call CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value = Application.UserName
    
    ' Gets current date and writes into respective cell
    Dim dtToday As Date
    dtToday = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = ComboBox14.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = commcomplete
    If OptionButton7 = True Then
        commcomplete = "Yes"
    End If
    If OptionButton8 = True Then
        commcomplete = "No"
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Call CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
' Hides User Form - "Cancel" Button
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Call CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Call CommandButton1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
' Hides User Form - "Cancel" Button
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = Application.UserName
    
    ' Gets current date and writes into respective cell
    Dim dtToday As Date
    dtToday = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Date
    
    If OptionButton1 = True Then
        complete = "Yes"
    End If
    If OptionButton2 = True Then
        complete = "No"
    End If

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = complete
    
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Label12_Click()

End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton8_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


' Installed
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Yes - Installed"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "No - Improper or Partial Installation"
     
' Powered
    ComboBox2.AddItem "Yes - 24VAC Power"
    ComboBox2.AddItem "No - Incomplete or No-Power"
        
' Uploaded
    ComboBox3.AddItem "Yes"
    ComboBox3.AddItem "No"
    ComboBox3.AddItem "Non-Applicable"

' Damper
    ComboBox4.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox4.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox4.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Sash/ODP
    ComboBox5.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox5.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox5.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Airflow
    ComboBox6.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox6.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox6.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Reheat
    ComboBox7.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox7.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox7.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Sup Temp
    ComboBox8.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox8.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox8.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Stat
    ComboBox9.AddItem "Yes - Operational"
    ComboBox9.AddItem "No - Improper or No Installation"
    ComboBox9.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' PPCL Loaded
    ComboBox10.AddItem "Yes - Loaded"
    ComboBox10.AddItem "No - Not Loaded"
    ComboBox10.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Pressurized
    ComboBox11.AddItem "Yes - Pressurized"
    ComboBox11.AddItem "No - Not or Improper Pressurization"
    ComboBox11.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
' Commissioning Agent
    ComboBox14.AddItem "Yes - Pressurized"
    ComboBox14.AddItem "No - Not or Improper Pressurization"
    ComboBox14.AddItem "Non-Applicable"
    
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = "Yes" Then OptionButton1 = True
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = "No" Then OptionButton2 = True

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = "Yes" Then OptionButton7 = True
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = "No" Then OptionButton8 = True
    
ComboBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
ComboBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
ComboBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
ComboBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
ComboBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
ComboBox6.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
ComboBox7.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
ComboBox8.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
ComboBox9.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
Label12.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
Label13.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
ComboBox10.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value
TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value
ComboBox11.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value
Label17.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
Label19.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
ComboBox14.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value
    
   
End Sub
```

The code is "working" but seems un realistic to have the same value typed out in every column. Also If I want a final box to say completed" I would need a very long conditional statement with the amount of separate active cells it needs to check.

Comment: See the famous [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and using arrays values all at once vs. each cell.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that you can do to improve readability and robustness of your code. A few suggestions to start with:

1. You should rename your ComboBoxes to reflect that actual data that's in them and command buttons to reflect the actual action being taken, do not simply use the default naming. So e.g. instead of CommandButton1 use cmdSubmit and instead of ComboBox1 use say cmbInstalled. This makes your code easier to understand.
2. Don't use ActiveCell as a reference point in your code, it is not robust. It relies on the end user selecting exactly the right cell before opening the form. If the form is to act on a selected row, then get a reference to the whole selected row.
3. Define named variables to refer to the columns that contain the data. I also suggest you use an Enum to enumerate the columns giving some meaningful name to each column. Then in the Userform_Initialize function you can set up references to all the relevant cells once, from then onwards you use the named variables.
4. You worry about having to have a lot of logic to check for completeness, but I suspect that's just the nature of the application. Put the completeness check into a function, and code it step by step. You can check for completeness just by calling the function.

That's just a start for you to be going on with.

Here is some example code to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
'// ALWAYS USE Option Explicit
Option Explicit

'// These are the columns in the sheet
'// that indicate which column each
'// name data item is stored in
Enum columns
    Installed = 1
    Powered = 2
    Uploaded = 3
    Damper = 4
    SashODP = 5
    AirFlow = 6
    Reheat = 7
    Date = 18
    UserName = 19
    '// etc
    
End Enum

'// This refers to the whole data row being modified
Dim rCurrentRow As Range

'// These are the cells in the row, named by what they hold
Dim rInstalled As Range
Dim rPowered As Range
Dim rUploaded As Range
Dim rDamper As Range
Dim rSashODP As Range
Dim rAirFlow As Range
Dim rReheat As Range
Dim rDate As Range
Dim rUserName As Range
'// etc


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    setupCurrentRow
    Debug.Print "Current row is #" & rCurrentRow.Row
    initializeComboBoxes
    loadFormDataFromRow
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    saveFormData
End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
    
Private Sub loadFormDataFromRow()
    cmbInstalled.Text = rInstalled.Value
    cmbPowered.Text = rPowered.Value
    '// etc...
    
End Sub

Private Sub saveFormData()

    ' Write the values of the combobox's into the respective cells
    rInstalled.Value = cmbInstalled.Value
    rPowered.Value = cmbPowered.Value
    rUploaded.Value = cmbUploaded.Value
    rDamper.Value = cmbDamper.Value
    '// etc
    
    
    rUserName.Value = Application.UserName
    rDate.Value = Now
    '// etc
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub



Private Sub setupCurrentRow()
    '// get a reference to the whole row that the user has selected
    Set rCurrentRow = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    
    '// set the named variables to the cells in the right column
    With rCurrentRow
        Set rInstalled = .Cells(columns.Installed)
        Set rPowered = .Cells(columns.Powered)
        Set rUploaded = .Cells(columns.Uploaded)
        Set rDamper = .Cells(columns.Damper)
        Set rSashODP = .Cells(columns.SashODP)
        Set rAirFlow = .Cells(columns.AirFlow)
        Set rReheat = .Cells(columns.Reheat)
        Set rUserName = .Cells(columns.UserName)
        Set rDate = .Cells(columns.Date)
        '// etc...
    End With
    
End Sub


Private Sub initializeComboBoxes()
    setCombo cmbInstalled, _
                "Yes - Installed", _
                "No - Improper or Partial Installation"
    setCombo cmbPowered, _
                "Yes - 24VAC Power", _
                "No - Incomplete or No-Power"
                
    '// Etc....
    
End Sub



Private Sub setCombo(combo As ComboBox, Optional v1 = "", Optional v2 = "", Optional v3 = "", Optional v4 = "", Optional v5 = "")
    With combo
        .Clear
        If Len(v1) > 0 Then .AddItem v1
        If Len(v2) > 0 Then .AddItem v2
        If Len(v3) > 0 Then .AddItem v3
        If Len(v4) > 0 Then .AddItem v4
        If Len(v5) > 0 Then .AddItem v5
    End With
    
End Sub
```